# DJS Leaderboard Rankings not showing properly

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I've had this leaderboard command for a while now and I decided that I wanted to show the user's rank if they aren't in the top 10 for the amount of coins that they had.

I tried adding it to the footer but instead of it showing their actual ranking it just displays their rank as the number of users in the actual database, even if they list in the top 10.

The description part, where it displays the top 10, works as it should though. I've added an image to further "explain" it. If this sounds confusing, the command was run by `gonoahwhere` whose ranking should say 1 instead of 3 in the footer.

```js
const { readdirSync } = require("fs");
const { EmbedBuilder, SlashCommandBuilder } = require("discord.js");
const config = require("../../config.json");
const botConf = require("../../config.js")
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const User = require("../../models/user");

module.exports = {
  data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName("leaderboard")
    .setDescription("Displays the richest across the Bot."),
  async execute(interaction) {
    
    let member = interaction.user;
    let memberData = await User.findOne({ id: member.id }) || new User({ _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(), id: member.id })
    
    let { username, id } = interaction.user;
    let { coins } = memberData.wallet
    
    const memberCoins = (memberData) => {
      if (memberData < 1e3) return memberData;
      if (memberData >= 1e3 && memberData < 1e6) return (memberData / 1e3).toFixed(2) + "K";
      if (memberData >= 1e6 && memberData < 1e9) return (memberData / 1e6).toFixed(2) + "M";
      if (memberData >= 1e9 && memberData < 1e12) return (memberData / 1e9).toFixed(2) + "B";
      if (memberData >= 1e12) return (memberData / 1e12).toFixed(2) + "T";
    }
    
    let members = await User.find({ "wallet.coins": { $gt:0 } }).sort({ "wallet.coins":-1 })
    if (!members) return console.log("Error: No members in database.")
    let memberIdx = members.findIndex((member) => member.userId === id) + 1
      
    let rank = members
      .slice(0, 10)
      .map((i) => `\`[${memberIdx = memberIdx + 1}]\` ∘ \`${interaction.client.users.cache.get(i.id)?.tag}\`: \`${memberCoins(i.wallet.coins)}\``)
      .join("\n")
      
    if (!members || members.length == 0)
      rank = "There are currently no members with coins!"

    let ranks = `You're ranked ${memberIdx} with ${memberCoins(memberData.wallet.coins) || 0} coins`
    
    if (!memberCoins(memberData.wallet.coins))
      ranks = `You're unranked with 0 coins`

    let leaderboardEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
      .setColor(botConf.embed.embedColor)
      .setAuthor({ name: "〔〕‒ NoahBoat Leaderboards" })
      .setThumbnail(interaction.user.displayAvatarURL())
      .setDescription(`∘∘∘ Here is the top 10 leaders for coins ∘∘∘\n\n${rank}`)
      .setFooter({ text: `${ranks}` })
      .setTimestamp()

    await interaction.reply({ embeds: [leaderboardEmbed] })
  },  
};
```

Leaderboard Preview:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're increasing the value of `memberIdx` on every iteration inside that `.map()`.

You could use the index of the current element being processed in the array (`i` in `map`'s callback) and avoid changing the `memberIdx` value, like this:

```js
let rank = members
  .slice(0, 10)
  .map(
    (member, i) =>
      `\`[${memberIdx + i + 1}]\` ∘ \`${
        interaction.client.users.cache.get(member.id)?.tag
      }\`: \`${memberCoins(member.wallet.coins)}\``,
  )
  .join('\n');
```

Comment: well `let ranks = \`You're ranked ${memberIdx} with ${memberCoins(memberData.wallet.coins) || 0} coins\`` is where its pulling the memberIdx for the embed footer, so I dont think the map function is whats causing the issue entirely however I did change it to not increase on every iteration like you suggested so now it just stays as "0" when the embed is sent on the footer line

Comment: I'm not sure how it could be `0`. It should be zero only if `members.findIndex` can't find the member and returns `-1`. Can you run your `/leaderboard` command as another user and check the footer again? If you run it as `jasperundergo` will the footer display `you're ranked 2`?

Comment: It still shows 0 for 2nd place too

https://imgur.com/hPb6EF1

Comment: I did `console.log(members.findIndex((member) => member.userId === id) + 1)` to check what that is logging when the command is run, which I believe is where the issue is coming from since it returns `0` no matter whos 1st, 2nd or 3rd etc. Now I just need to figure out why it doesnt changed based on the amount of coins users have.